# How to limit bandwidth (file sync) to a specific windows file share (smb - raid1 backup device)?

Tags: backup, raid-1

So I decided that I needed a Raid1 backup device for the home.
Mostly to backup documents and media.
There will be about 3-4 Windows systems in the household that would sync files to this device.

I need an app/feature/program that would limit the bandwidth (or have a 'sync while idle' feature) while syncing to this share for each system that is syncing.  dropbox has such a feature.

any advice would be appreciated.

tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backup software called "CrashPlan" has this feature.  The software gives you several backup options, including backing up to another computer on your network.

Setting up your backups is outside the scope here, but after you're finished with that, you can adjust CrashPlan's bandwidth usage.  Go to Settings > Network.  The settings under the "LAN" column will affect bandwidth usage on your internal, home network; Settings under the "WAN" column would affect backup traffic that goes over the internet (like if you use their "cloud" backup service for example).  It sounds like the setting you need is the "limit sending rate..." one under the LAN column.  Set the "away" one to the maximum bandwidth you want to be used while the PC is idle (unused), and the "present" one to the max bandwidth you want used when someone is actively using the PC.

Here is a link to CrashPlan: https://www.code42.com/crashplan/